# Include Bootstrap in Electron React app

Tags: electron

I have an electron-react app. I need to use Bootstrap for styling.
Earlier I used bootstrap from CDN, and it worked like a charm. But I need my application to even work offline.

So I need to somehow embed Bootstrap inside my app. I tried downloading bootstrap locally and then using its css files inside the app, but I happen to see that when I package my application I don't find 
Bootstrap in the packaged version. I put the CSS folder inside the app folder itself. It worked when I ran 'npm run start', but didn't when I packaged the app.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

When I package the app, it gives FILE NOT FOUND for bootstrap.min.css

I know I have a way to use npm package for bootstrap. But even that doesn't work when packaging the app.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

This gave the same error for FILE NOT FOUND.

I prioritise on using raw CSS file for bootstrap, but if have a working solution with npm package please mention.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does your file structure look like? try without "../" in the href or with one "../" more...

Comment: Tried, got no luck with the packaged app

Comment: Can you examine the contents of your packaged app, and see where exactly that file is?